# Why is a FIX connection dropping heartbeats when both endpoints are on the same server?

Tags: quickfix

We have two applications using QuickFIX engine, both are running in the same machine.
Sometimes we see that the session ends due to lack of heartbeats.

How can it be since both are running on the same machine?

Comment: What do the message logs say?

Comment: we see that a disconnect in the event file of QuickFIX

Comment: Event logs are crap.  Look at the message logs, to see the actual messages being transmitted.

Answer (score 2):

FIX heartbeat mechanism has nothing to do with the fact where applications communicating using FIX protocol run. If you see the session being dropped due to lack of heartbeat then you have to determine which session did not send heartbeat (it will also fail to respond to «Test Request» message, if any) and why did that happen. Possible reasons are:

- Server and client have different heartbeat interval settings and server does not honor client's heartbeat interval (field #108 in «Logon» message) and test request/response logic is broken (or turned off).
- Underlying transport errors (i.e. TCP/IP errors or UDP packet drops).
- Other software/hardware bugs.
- Something else.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!